# Desktop showing multiple times

Tags: 18.04, display, screen

As you can it doesn't display properly. Can somebody help?

When I use command `xrandr` I get:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   1600x900      59.82  
   1400x900      59.88  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1280x800      59.91    59.81  
   1280x720      59.86    59.74  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x576      59.90    59.82  
   960x540       59.82    59.63  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   800x450       59.82  
   700x450       59.88  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   640x400       59.98    59.88  
   640x360       59.86    59.83  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.82    59.63  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

[image: Laptops screen]

Comment: That's interesting... Can you open the terminal by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` and type `xrandr`. Then copy and paste the text into your question.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It helps a little, like why are there seven disconnected external monitors `DP-0` to `DP-6`? However I've never seen this problem before and I'm stumped. Hopefully someone else has come across this problem before.

Comment: What happens when you go to settings, Time&Date, Check if you have Time in other locations unchecked.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @An0n If you mean automatic date & time I have that checked

Comment: @JuusoÄijälä I can't see the pictures clearly, whats actually the problem ?

Comment: @An0n it show 6 copies of my desktop on my laptops built-in-screen at the same time

Comment: @JuusoÄijälä Do you have workspaces on ?

Comment: @An0n I don't think this has anything to with the workspaces because those desktops are just copies of each other and the display is clearly glitching. And I can't find where to turn workspaces on/off in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @JuusoÄijälä Get unity tweak tool.

Comment: @An0n error while installing package: new nvidia-gl-390

Comment: @JuusoÄijälä Is this a fresh installation? Or was this happend suddenly?